# implementing HttpRequestHandler in LWUIT

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

i'm trying to implement a HttpRequestHandler on my j2me application. When i try to execute ,is giving me this error cannot find symbol
       HttpRequestHandler handler = new HttpRequestHandler();

```
 HttpRequestHandler handler = new HttpRequestHandler();
                HTMLComponent htmlC = new HTMLComponent(handler);
                htmlC.setPage("http://m.facebook.com");

           Form form = new Form("HTML Test");
            form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,htmlC);
            form.show();
```

i'm new to j2me and please help .

Comment: Sounds like you haven't imported HttpRequestHandler

Comment: I have not imported HttpRequestHandler, please help me on how to go about it,i'm new to j2me programming

Comment: How can i import an HttpRequestHandler? i kindly request for your assistance

Comment: I have understood you but the problem is the inbuilt library cannot be found

Comment: add this to your class `import com.sun.lwuit.browser.HttpRequestHandler`

Comment: The error has disappeared but is telling me the package com does not exist ... thanks in advance

Comment: Which IDE are you using? NetBeans? Eclipse?

Comment: Im using netbeans thanks so much all of you it has worked after importing

Comment: import com.sun.lwuit.browser.HttpRequestHandler